# Ubuntu 16.04.2 -- MongoDB not installed but 2 mongod processes eating up RAM

Tags: juju, ram, mongodb

I'm running an install of Ubuntu 16.04.2 that I've been playing with (Landscape, Juju, LXD). Recently, in the past few days, after I reboot, the system (i7 5820K, 16Gb DDR4) will grind to a halt. Glances and gnome-system-monitor show two processes, both belonging to root, called mongod with each have consumed almost six gigabytes of RAM.

I use a lot of Firefox tabs so this means that my memory use hits nearly 100% and things slow down drastically due to using my swapfile.

`sudo killall mongod` does not kill the processes. Only running `sudo pkill [PID]` actually kills them, and even after that sometimes the two processes come back, although this time using only about 30Mb of RAM each.

Also, I have not installed MongoDB or anything related at all. Running `apt autoremove` using `*mongo*` shows nothing installed.

I was curious as to whether or not Juju had anything to do with it so I uninstalled everything Juju- and Landscape-related. However, I've rebooted a few times since then and still these processes exist.

Here's proof that nothing Juju- or MongoDB-related are installed on my system:

```
snyper@machine1:~$ sudo apt autoremove *mongo*
[sudo] password for snyper: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'jmeter-mongodb' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python-mongoengine' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'ruby-mongo' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python2.7-pymongo' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python3-pymongo-ext' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python-mongoengine-doc' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'juju-mongodb2.6' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'juju-mongo-tools3.2' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'juju-mongodb3.2' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongodb-perl' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongodbx-class-perl' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libcatmandu-store-mongodb-perl' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python3-mongoengine' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongo-client0' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python2.7-pymongo-ext' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python3-pymongo' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'ruby-em-mongo' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-server' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongo-client0-dbg' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongoc-1.0-0' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python2.7-mongoengine' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongo-client-dev' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongo-client-doc' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'php-mongo' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'php-horde-mongo' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongoc-dbg' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongoc-dev' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongoc-doc' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'juju-mongodb' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'syslog-ng-mod-mongodb' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python-pymongo-doc' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python-pymongo' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-clients' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'python-pymongo-ext' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'puppet-module-puppetlabs-mongodb' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'libmongodb-java' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'php-mongodb' for glob '*mongo*'
Note, selecting 'php-doctrine-mongodb-odm' for glob '*mongo*'
Package 'php-doctrine-mongodb-odm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php-horde-mongo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php-mongo' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'python-mongoengine' instead of 'python2.7-mongoengine'
Note, selecting 'python-pymongo' instead of 'python2.7-pymongo'
Note, selecting 'python-pymongo-ext' instead of 'python2.7-pymongo-ext'
Package 'python-pymongo-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python3-pymongo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python3-pymongo-ext' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'jmeter-mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-mongo-tools3.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-mongodb2.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libcatmandu-store-mongodb-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongo-client-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongo-client-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongo-client0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongo-client0-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongoc-1.0-0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongoc-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongoc-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongoc-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongodb-java' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongodb-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmongodbx-class-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-clients' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php-mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'puppet-module-puppetlabs-mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-mongoengine' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-mongoengine-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-pymongo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-pymongo-ext' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python3-mongoengine' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ruby-em-mongo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ruby-mongo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'syslog-ng-mod-mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-mongodb3.2' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

snyper@machine1:~$ sudo apt autoremove *juju*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'juju2' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-deployer' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-1' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'python3-jujuclient' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-1-default' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-mongodb2.6' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-mongo-tools3.2' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-mongodb3.2' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'golang-juju-loggo-dev' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'python-jujubundlelib' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-core2' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-local' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'python3-jujubundlelib' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'python-txjuju' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-1.25' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-core' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-2.0' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-mongodb' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'golang-github-juju-loggo-dev' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'golang-github-juju-ratelimit-dev' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'python-jujuclient' for glob '*juju*'
Note, selecting 'juju-local-kvm' for glob '*juju*'
Package 'juju2' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'juju-1.25' instead of 'juju-1'
Package 'juju-core2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'golang-juju-loggo-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'golang-github-juju-loggo-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'golang-github-juju-ratelimit-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-deployer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-mongo-tools3.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-mongodb2.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-jujubundlelib' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python3-jujubundlelib' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-1-default' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-1.25' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-core' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-local' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-local-kvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-mongodb3.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-jujuclient' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python3-jujuclient' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'juju-2.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-txjuju' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

I'm just really confused as to why this is happening, and how I can remove whatever it is that's causing this from my system.

Comment: Yes, juju stores its data in mongo-db. can you share the output of $ dpkg -l | grep juju

Comment: @Junaid  there is no output. `dpkg -l | grep juju` simply exits to the next line.

Comment: Is there any mongodb service running? sudo service mongod status?

Comment: `● mongod.service   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)   Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: `lsof +L1` will show you processes that are running and are using deleted files.

Comment: `lsof - p <pid>` will show you the open files for specific process to see the location of the binaries for mongod. There's other option - You also might have been hacked if you were careless when you played, like not setting strong passwords, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this is simple. `conjure-up` deployed several LXC containers for use with Juju, and those containers were running on boot and contained the `mongod` process that was eating up my RAM.

To fix this, we list the existing containers with `lxc list`.

Then we stop them with `lxc stop [containername]`

and delete them with `lxc delete [containername]`

and now our problem has been solved.